# Merging workbooks into a new file

Tags: excel, vba, file, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple Excel files from one Folder into a new file. I've found a solution on the Internet, that is adding my files into an open one. I'm not really into VBA Excel, so I think it's a basic problem, but I can't do it, things I've tried haven't worked properly. I would like to change the following code to create a new file called "summary" in the "Path" and copy the Sheets into this new file, overwriting the file every time I do it and deleting the several source files after doing this.

Is there a possibility of merging all those files into one without opening everyone of it?

```
Sub GetSheets() 
Path = "C:\Merging\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While FileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(FileName).Close
FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *almost* works as is, just needs a couple of slight tweaks. I also agree with @AnalystCave that if this is a repeating exercise, you may consider a more streamlined solution. But this will work for you.

> **EDIT:** changed to deal with existing destination file -- if it exists and is open, then connect to it otherwise open it; then delete all sheets in the existing file to prepare for the copies

```vb
Option Explicit

Function IsSheetEmpty(sht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    IsSheetEmpty = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht.Cells) = 0
End Function

Sub GetSheets()
    Dim Path, Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim appSheets As Integer
    Dim srcFile As String
    Dim dstFile As String
    Dim dstPath As String
    Dim wasntAlreadyOpen As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'go faster by not waiting for display

    '--- create a new workbook with only one worksheet
    dstFile = "AllSheetsHere.xlsx"
    dstPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & dstFile
    wasntAlreadyOpen = True
    If Dir(dstPath) = "" Then
        '--- the destination workbook does not (yet) exist, so create it
        appSheets = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook  'saves the default number of new sheets
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1          'force only one new sheet
        Set newBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
        newBook.SaveAs dstFile
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = appSheets  'restores the default number of new sheets
    Else
        '--- the destination workbook exists, so ...
        On Error Resume Next
        wasntAlreadyOpen = False
        Set newBook = Workbooks(dstFile)             'connect if already open
        If newBook Is Nothing Then
            Set newBook = Workbooks.Open(dstPath)    'open if needed
            wasntAlreadyOpen = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        '--- make sure to delete any/all worksheets so we're only left
        '    with a single empty sheet named "Sheet1"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False            'we dont need to see the warning message
        Do While newBook.Sheets.Count > 1
            newBook.Sheets(newBook.Sheets.Count).Delete
        Loop
        newBook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
        newBook.Sheets(1).Cells.ClearContents
        newBook.Sheets(1).Cells.ClearFormats
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True             'turn alerts back on
    End If

    Path = "C:\Temp\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls?")  'add the ? to pick up *.xlsx and *.xlsm files
    Do While Filename <> ""
        srcFile = Path & Filename
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=srcFile, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            '--- potentially check for blank sheets, or only sheets
            '    with specific data on them
            If Not IsSheetEmpty(Sheet) Then
                Sheet.Copy After:=newBook.Sheets(1)
            End If
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close (False) 'add False to close without saving
        Kill srcFile                      'deletes the file
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    '--- delete the original empty worksheet and save the book
    If newBook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
        newBook.Sheets(1).Delete
    End If
    newBook.Save
    '--- leave it open if it was already open when we started
    If wasntAlreadyOpen Then
        newBook.Close
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 're-enable screen updates
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! But I would like to change the following code to create a new file called "summary" in the "Path" and copy the Sheets into this new file, overwriting the file every time I do it and delete the several source files after doing this.

Comment: I've updated the code above to show how to create an empty workbook and copy your sheets and delete each file.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The Problem is, that it's not really working. "newBook.SaveAs dstFile"  always ocurrs an error, saying that it can not find the file A or C...always with a different number. It deletes the files in the source Folder, but the new file does not occur...

Comment: If you still wanted to store the file in the current directory (same directory as the workbook with your macro), the path should have been built with a separator like this `dstFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "AllSheetsHere.xlsx"`.

Comment: Changes added above to delete the sheets and prepare the file. Plus the code will connect to the destination file if it's already open.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, regardless of your solution you will still need to OPEN every Excel workbook if you want to merge all of them.

**Secondly**, I think you might want to rephrase your question to *"Is there a possibility of merging all those files into one faster or in any easier way?"*

From the level of Excel VBA there is really no other way then opening each Workbook within the same Application level. ***If this is a one-time exercise*** I would stick to the code you already have and bear with it. 
However, ***if this is an exercise you will be doing repeatedly*** and need an efficient solution, your only option is resorting to the OpenXML format which does not require a heavyweight Excel process e.g. ***creating a C# solution using the ClosedXML library. This will definitely reduce the time needed to consolidate your workbooks.***